# Javascript: Array of milliseconds to array of dates

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, datetime

I've got some behavior I don't understand when I'm trying to take my input array of milliseconds and change them to dates with Date(). For example:

```
0: 1582641000
1: 1582727400
2: 1582813800
3: 1582900200
4: 1583159400
5: 1583245800
6: 1583332200
7: 1583418600
8: 1583505000
9: 1583760600
10: 1583847000
```

So far I've used pretty simple functions to do this, like:

```
for (i = 0; i < timestamp.length; i++) {
    timestamp[i] = Date(timestamp[i]);
}
```

Strangely, to me at least, this makes every element of "timestamp" the same date value. Similarly, if I do:

```
for (i = 0; i < timestamp.length; i++) {
    timestamp[i] = new Date(timestamp[i]);
}
```

Now every date in the "timestamp" array is in Jan 19 1970.
What's going on here? How can I get the correct human readable string array from this? I.E.: Mar 25 2020 20:50:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)?

Comment: First multiply with 1000 to convert UNIX timestame in seconds to convert into milliseconds and then use ``toLocaleDateString("en-US")`` to convert it into date-time format.  So you can do like this `` timestamp[i] = new Date(timestamp[i] * 1000).toLocaleDateString("en-US");``

Comment: How I didn't notice to my data was in seconds and not milliseconds is beyond me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Date constructor accepts *milliseconds* as a single parameter, not seconds. Multiply the number by 1000 first.

You also must use `new`, otherwise the resulting date string will be at the current time, [not the timestamp of the parameter](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-value). (All arguments are ignored without `new`)

Use `.map` instead of a `for` loop, and call `toUTCString`:

```js
const arr = [
  1582641000,
  1582727400,
  1582813800,
  1582900200,
  1583159400,
  1583245800,
  1583332200,
  1583418600,
  1583505000,
  1583760600,
  1583847000,
];
const arrOfDates = arr.map(secs => new Date(secs * 1000).toUTCString());
console.log(arrOfDates);
```

Comment: How I didn't notice to my data was in seconds and not milliseconds is beyond me...